# The term '-alias' is not recognized , while generating SHA1 key for firebase

Tags: firebase, sha1

while generating the SHA1 key for firebase , I was using this command

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

then I got this error

```
-alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystor ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and someone suggested me this command

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore"
```

now I am getting this error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:917)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:419)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:412)
PS D:\# Source Code\Projects\Find the fellowers\findfellows>
```

Plz help , or suggest any tutorial video for Firebase integration with flutter project

I am trying to generate SHA1 key for Firebase connection with my flutter project and I am facing several errors , I would like someone to help me out.